# SectionIndexTitle in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I am creating list in TableView according to this [tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/indexed-table-view-ios-tutorial-ios11). However I would like to have all leters in IndexTitle. It is OK, if I only add all leters to `carSectionTitles` array? I think it doesn't work correctly in simulator. Could someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

This is by no means an elegant solution, but in your view did load, replace:

`// 2
carSectionTitles = [String](carsDictionary.keys)
carSectionTitles = carSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })`

with the following:

```
// 2
carSectionTitles = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "U", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

With everything else the same I think this will do what you want.

Comment: How can I do that more elegantly? I would like to learn it. btw, as I mentioned, I tried this, but I think it doesn't work correctly.